# Is there an option in photoshop to find the average darkness of pixel color of a certain image?

Tags: images, colors, adobe-photoshop

I'm trying to compare the brownness of multiple apple slices using photoshop and it has sucked me down a rabbit hole on the internet with information completely overwhelming me. My goal is to compare ways that prevent food browning but I am out of my element using photoshop. I tried to convert images to greyscale and find the average darkness of the images. Not totally sure if that is how greyscale works. Trying to compare the darkness of color, but not sure if greyscale is used for the brightness of color or whatnot. I may not be able to understand the mechanics of how this works but I'm desperate for some enlightenment. Any help would be greatly, greatly appreciated. Also, https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/viewing-histograms-pixel-values.html shows that histograms can be used to find the average intensity of pixels of an image. Can this be used to find the average "darkness" of an image?

Comment: Photo StackExchange shows hot to do what you ask for, take an average of the RGB values over a region: https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/86846/how-to-calculate-average-color-for-some-part-of-picture#_=_ "Using Photoshop, you can use the color sampler tool and select a suitable sample size"

Comment: [This thread may be of interest](https://community.adobe.com/t5/photoshop-ecosystem-discussions/automatcally-export-lab-or-rgb-histogram-values-from-a-selection/td-p/8529956)